# How to make TTS speak when touchevent type is down and move just as talkback?

Tags: android, text-to-speech, touch-event, talkback

I am trying to override the talkback, but confused about how it could speak the focus information when the motionevent is down and move.

According to the example of Accessibility, my service could only speak after the finger lift up.

Where to set the speak moment? thanks a lot!

Comment: Your question is pretty confusing, the most important part of your question is in your heading. I think I got it now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is pretty simple.  Assuming you're starting from a properly configured accessibility service, you would want to do the following:

```
public class A11yService extends AccessibilityService {

    @Override
    public void onAccessibilityEvent(AccessibilityEvent e) {
        switch (e.getEventType()) {
            case AccessibilityEvent.TYPE_VIEW_HOVER_ENTER:
                //Do your work here. 
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

Notice that the code above is responding only to Accessibility Hover Events. This is the key. This example won't replicate TalkBack's functionality, TalkBack does much much more than this. However, if your question is "How does TalkBack speak items while gliding finger across the screen?" this is the answer.

Comment: btw I am a designer, trying to improving mobile accessibility for one-handed use.It will be my pleasure to initiate the contact with you.

Comment: I would like that. You can find my LinkedIn in my SatckOverflow profile.